# Hypothesis for differentiating under the integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-explanation

I've been trying to understand when it is allowed to move a derivative inside the integral, especifically the requirements on the derivative of the function being integrated.
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^bf(x,y)dy=\int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)dy$$
In some sources I find that it just requires that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)$ be continuous in some neighbourhood while in others it is also required that there exists a function $g(y)$ such that $|\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)|<g(y)$.

Can someone please explain to me if/when the second hypothesisis not necessary?

Comment: See [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Answer (score 1):

The Dominated Convergence Theorem can be used to explain the second hypothesis. Let $f_n(x,y) = n(f(x+1/n,y)-f(x,y))$ which converges to the derivative $\partial_x f(x,y)$. If there exists a function $g(y)$ such that $|\partial_x f(x,y)|\leq g(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ is integrable in $y$, then the derivative (which is just a limit) can be interchanged with the integral. Usually it's easier to deduce a function $g(y)$ instead.

So if for each $x$, $\partial_x f(x,y)$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $y\in [a,b]$ that should suffice since you can just bound it by $g(x,y)$ being a constant function that's large enough.

Comment: Thank you. So just to clarify, the second hypothesis becomes necessary only  if you have a inproper integral, where you can't necessarily bound the derivative with a large enough function?